# The motivation for multidimensional CUDA block grid

Tags: cuda

I have basically the same question as posed [in this discussion](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/655575/cuda-motivation-for-multi-dimensional-kernel-execution/?offset=6). In particular I want to refer to this final response:

> I think there are two different questions mixed together in this
>   thread:
>
> 1. Is there a performance benefit to using a 2D or 3D mapping of input or output data to threads? The answer is "absolutely" for all the
>      reasons you and others have described. If the data or calculation has
>      spatial locality, then so should the assignment of work to threads in
>      a warp.
> 2. Is there a performance benefit to using CUDA's multidimensional grids to do this work assignment? In this case, I don't think so since
>      you can do the index calculation trivially yourself at the top of the
>      kernel. This burns a few arithmetic instructions, but that should be
>      negligible compared to the kernel launch overhead.
>
> This is why I think the multidimensional grids are intended as a
>   programmer convenience rather than a way to improve performance. You
>   do absolutely need to think about each warp's memory access patterns,
>   though.

I want to know if this situation still holds today. I want to know the reason why there is a need for a multidimensional "outer" grid.

What I'm trying to understand is whether or not there is a significant purpose to this (e.g. an actual benefit from spatial locality) or is it there for convenience (e.g. in an image processing context, is it there only so that we can have CUDA be aware of the x/y "patch" that a particular block is processing so it can report it to the CUDA Visual Profiler or something)?

A third option is that this nothing more than a holdover from earlier versions of CUDA where it was a workaround for hardware indexing limits.

Answer (score 8):

There is definitely a benefit in the use of multi-dimensional grid. The different entries (tid, ctaid) are read-only variables visible as special registers. See [PTX ISA](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#special-registers)

> PTX includes a number of predefined, read-only variables, which are visible as special registers and accessed through mov or cvt instructions.
> The special registers are:
>
> ```
>  %tid
>  %ntid
>  %laneid
>  %warpid
>  %nwarpid
>  %ctaid
>  %nctaid
> ```

If some of this data may be used without further processing, not-only you may gain arithmetic instructions - potentially at each indexing step of multi-dimension data, but more importantly you are saving registers which is a very scarce resource on any hardware.